# Python - Verify if a value is in a column, replace by value in different column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

df:

```
 index   some_variable identifier1  identifier2 
  1        x             AB2          AB3
  2        x             BB2          BB3
  3        x             CB2          CB3
  4        y             DB2          DB3
  5        y             EB2          EB3
```

dfa:

```
 index   some_variable identifier1  identifier2 identifier3
  1        x             AB5          AB3          AB3
  2        x             BB5          BB2          AB2
  3        x             CB5          CB2          AB5
  4        y             DB5          DB3          AB3
  5        y             EB5          EB3          AB3
```

if an element of `df['identifier1']` is in `dfa['identifier2']` replace for that index `df['identifier2']` by `dfa['identifier3']`, if some_variable is equal to `'x'`. So the condition is:

```
[(df['identifier1'].isin(dfa['identifier2'])&(df[some_variable]=='x')]
```

and I want:

```
 index   some_variable identifier1  identifier2 
  1        x             AB2          AB3
  2        x             BB2          AB2
  3        x             CB2          AB5
  4        y             DB2          DB3
  5        y             EB2          EB3
```

I can set up the condition, but can't figure out how to get the output.

Comment: Your description doesn't make a lot of sense. Please clarify.

Comment: If I follow your logic correctly, `df` will have no changes, since none of the values in `df['identifier1']` are in `dfa`.

Comment: I think the logic is wrong and the user has dfa and df swapped around in the isin. Just a guess though.

Comment: sorry, seems like i switched around the names of the two dataframes

Comment: The solution I've suggested is basically there (except you've swapped the df names now) but you need to clarify which df 'some_variable' needs to be x in. Both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
df1

#    index some_variable identifier1 identifier2
# 0      1             x         AB2         AB3
# 1      2             x         BB2         BB3
# 2      3             x         CB2         CB3
# 3      4             y         DB2         DB3
# 4      5             y         EB2         EB3

df2

#    index some_variable identifier1 identifier2 identifier3
# 0      1             x         AB5         AB3         AB3
# 1      2             x         BB5         BB2         AB2
# 2      3             x         CB5         CB2         AB5
# 3      4             y         DB5         DB3         AB3
# 4      5             y         EB5         EB3         AB3

idx = df1['identifier1'].isin(df2['identifier2']) & (df1['some_variable'] == 'x')
df1.loc[idx, 'identifier2'] = df2['identifier3']

df1

#    index some_variable identifier1 identifier2
# 0      1             x         AB2         AB3
# 1      2             x         BB2         AB2
# 2      3             x         CB2         AB5
# 3      4             y         DB2         DB3
# 4      5             y         EB2         EB3
```

Comment: Returns a list of NaN values. If I replace = df2['identifier3']   by a fixed value it works. (so: = 2  works). It seems to not match directly to the correct row of df2.

Comment: @Peter, not sure what you mean. My output is identical to the output you require.

Comment: You're right, it works on the subsample as provided. Must be something wrong when I try to scale it up. I'll figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following (although there might be an more simple way to do it)

```
d1 = {'some_variable':['x','x','x','y','y'], 'identifier1':['AB2','BB2','CB2','DB2','EB2'], 'identifier2':['AB3','BB3','CB3','DB3','EB3']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d1)

d2 = {'some_variable':['x','x','x','y','y'], 'identifier1':['AB5','BB5','CB5','DB5','EB5'], 'identifier2':['AB3','BB2','CB2','DB3','EB3'], 'identifier3':['AB3','AB2','AB5','AB3','AB3']}
dfa = pd.DataFrame(d2)

df['identifier2'][(df['identifier1'].isin(dfa['identifier2']) & (df['some_variable'] == 'x'))] = dfa['identifier3'][
    (df['identifier1'].isin(dfa['identifier2']) & (df['some_variable'] == 'x'))]
```

Comment: Returns: ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Comment: Not sure what to suggest; it works for me. I've added the dataframe I'm using, maybe you can spot the issue?

Comment: Fair enough, must be something else going on when I scale this up to full data. I'll look into it.